# How to simply convert video files (i.e.: MKV to MP4)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I simply want to convert files, any format to any format (at the moment, I need to convert MKV to MP4-h264), without losing quality. I don't want to resize (scale) the video, I don't want to change its aspect ratio and I don't want it to lose quality (this is very important); all I want is "to change the format", that's all. Reason: my DVD player won't recognize any formats other than AVI or MP4. I don't care about file size, unless the difference between the input and the output files is absurdly huge. So, how do I do that?

I've already tried programs such as WinFF, Arista, Format Junkie, but their presets always change something which I don't want to be changed (size, aspec ratio, etc.). I'm not really sure, but I think the best way to get what I want is to go with the pure ffmpeg commands. But how?

By the way, Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit), here. Thanks for your time, guys.

Comment: How about http://www.noobslab.com/2013/06/ff-multi-converter-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: It seems to be interesting, vivid_vibe. I'll give it a try. Let's see what it can do. Thanks. :)

Comment: Dumindu Mahawela, I followed the link you provided and came across this command: "avconv -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4". This worked like a charm for me. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Post it as a answer here.

Answer (score 366):

If you only want to convert MKV to MP4 then you will save quality and a lot of time by just changing the containers. Both of these are just wrappers over the same content so the CPU only needs to do a little work. Don't re encode as you will definitely lose quality.

It's very straight forward using `ffmpeg`:

```sh
ffmpeg -i LostInTranslation.mkv -codec copy LostInTranslation.mp4
```

Here, you are copying the video codec and audio codec so nothing is being encoded.

Tip: To convert all MKV files in the current directory, run a simple loop in terminal:

```sh
for i in *.mkv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy "${i%.*}.mp4"
done
```

For future conversions, like from AVI to MP4, check out [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: Sayem, I tried your suggestion, but got this result: "[mp4 @ 0x134da20] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: -2 >= -2
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument". Anyway, I've got what I want with the following command: "avconv -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4" which is pretty similar to the one you suggested. Thanks a lot for your time. :)

Comment: That for-loop dies when there are spaces in the file names ;-;

Comment: And don't forget `-movflags +faststart` because mp4 sucks; without that, you can't play a partial file (where the end of the file isn't written yet).

Comment: How come when I "re-wrap" MKV files as MP4 files, the subtitles in the original MKV aren't being transferred over??

Comment: @Anthony: Probably because the FFmpeg command didn't include instructions how to convert subtitle streams. My changes (`-codec copy`) should take care of that because they tell FFmpeg to copy all encountered data streams and codecs.

Comment: Windows users may need to add the `-strict experimental` flag after the input file for this to work: `ffmpeg -i LostInTranslation.mkv -strict experimental -codec copy LostInTranslation.mp4`. According to [this bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/209), the `-strict` option must be specified after the input file; otherwise, it will not recognize that you specified the option. That took me quite a while to find out.

Comment: @Alexander I am on Windows 10, did not use the `-strict` flag, and had no problems.  FYI.  In any case, the bug report is 9 years old and was closed 9 years ago.

Comment: Amazing. This just saved me an hour of conversion. Is there any way to make `ffmpeg` choose the fastest option possible for any conversion? I suppose that changing for example `.mov` to `.mp4` might require different options and a command that just guesses the best command would be amazing.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but rewrote this piece to make it work on Windows
`for %%f in (.\*.mkv) do ( 
    ffmpeg -i "%%~nf.mkv" -codec copy "%%~nf.mp4"
)`

Comment: Add option `-map 0` if your video has multiple audio tracks. Otherwise, this will only copy the first audio track.

Comment: Good god, I've been absolutely blasting my CPU for so, so many hours before I learned of this.

Answer (score 17):

Here is one you haven't tried. [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Comment: TheHerk, I couldn't install it. Added PPA, updated sources, tried to install "handbrake" package, but it says there's no such package to be installed. Go figure!

Comment: Never mind, TheHerk. I found the correct name of the package: handbrake-gtk. Installed it, but didn't like it. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Handbrake is incapable of lossless video conversion, as specified in the OP's question.  It has no "copy" option for video.  It is only capable of transcoding, which will always cause a loss of quality.

Comment: It may be true that handbrake doesn't have any lossless options, but the second statement is absolutely not true. You can convert from one data type to another without losing quality as long as the second can store more information that the first. https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21623

Comment: Handbrake is slow as H3ll, use the below python script ...

import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    if 'mkv' in f: 
        os.system('ffmpeg -i "' + str(f) + '" -codec copy "' + str(f).split('.mkv')[0] + '.mp4"')

Comment: @PanDe Generally bad practice to just plop strings directly into a command, so probably shouldn't suggest it to someone who might be unfamiliar with python; a better way would be to also import `subprocess` and use `files = [ f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f) and f[-4:] == '.mkv' ]` followed by `for f in files: subprocess.Popen([ 'ffmpeg', '-i', f, '-codec', 'copy', f[:-4] + '.mp4' ])`