# Open .vc extension ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, plugins, video-player

I am trying to open a **.vc extension** on ubuntu 18.04.

***What I have tried?***

1. As far as this link says

   https://www.filemagic.com/en/developer-files/vc-file-extension/the-four-best-ways-to-open-vc-files/

   these softwares are suggested:

   - VIVID 2.0 INCLUDE FILE WITH COLOR DEFINITIONS
   - SONARC COMPRESSED VOC AUDIO
   - VERGE CODE FILE
   - VISICALC SPREADSHEET FILE

   But these are all windows based.
2. I have also tried these online video converters and failed.

   - https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4
   - http://www.convertfiles.com/
   - https://www.video2edit.com/convert-to-mp4

***What i want***

**How can i open vc extension in ubuntu?**

preferably without using wine or stuff like that. (And i am not even sure that wine can handle verge or vivid or ...!)

Comment: First, .vc is associated with multiple types of software, so is your file a video, a spreadsheet, a code file ? Where does it come from ?
To know so, try to open it with a text editor, if you can see text it may be a script, if it is completely random chars it may be binary, so a multimedia file.

Comment: @Kwaadpepper it's a video

Comment: Have you tried VLC ? https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Kwaadpepper yes and i failed. it shows random photos from the original video.

Comment: Maybe here you would find some answers https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux

Comment: You could also try to convert it with ffmpeg https://askubuntu.com/questions/396883/how-to-simply-convert-video-files-i-e-mkv-to-mp4

```ffmpeg -i videofile.vc -codec copy videofile.mp4```
 This has to be run in terminal of course

Comment: Thank you but ffmpeg doesn't support vc files :( and it says "Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: Have you tried to install more codecs from restricted ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/783810/quicktime-player-installation  https://itsfoss.com/install-media-codecs-ubuntu/

Comment: Also you could have some more info using the vlc command : ```clvc``` to open your file

Comment: You can also try mediainfo  ```sudo apt install mediainfo``` or ```sudo apt install mediainfo-gui```

Comment: I tried with installing codecs and it failed. and the other players couldnt play it either :(

Comment: I can't find info on .vc file on internet. Except this https://communication.aver.com/model/vcplayer i'm out of ideas sorry I think it is some kind of non standard format, so only the software that produced this format will be able to read it.

Comment: Anyway thank you so much for your time :) @Kwaadpepper